# Can't shovel string into new array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, substring

I am trying to search an array for a substring and if that substring exists, shovel it into a new array. The problem I am having is that it keeps coming back with this error message:

```
`block in substrings': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

I have verified that the `index` in the method is not `nil` by printing it. I have also done `index == nil` to double check.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
new_array = []

def substrings(word, array)

  new_array = array.each do |index|

    if index.include? (word)

      p index
      p index == nil

      new_array << index

    end
  end
end


dictionary = ["below", "down", "go", "going", "horn", "how", "howdy", "it", "i", "low", "own", "part", "partner", "sit"]

substrings("i", dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically combine two different ways of solving this problem. The first is to assign the `new_array` the result of looping though the array, but in that case, the new_array variable is not available to use inside the block.

So you could either choose to create the variable first, like this

```
new_array = []

array.each do |index| 
  if index.include?(word)
    new_array << index
  end
end
```

Alternatively you could use a method called `reduce` which takes a more functional programming approach. That could look like this

```
new_array = array.reduce([]) do |arr, index| 
  if index.include?(word)
    arr << index
  else
    arr
  end
end
```

What reduce does is that the block argument `arr` is always set to the return value of the previous block execution. that can make the syntax a little longer than it has to be, so Ruby also has an alternate approach to reduce, called `each_with_object`, that does the same, but by mutating the same variable, instead of requiring a return value. I actually prefer this way and would solve it like this.

```
new_array = array.each_with_object([]) do |index, arr| 
  arr << index if index.include?(word)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend a bit the (correct) answer given by @DanneManne: While it is correct that you can access local variables from outer blocks from within an inner block, you can't do it within a `def`, and it is unnecessary in your example, because you can initialize `new_array` inside the body of your method and return it as result. But in case you ever really need this kind of construct, there indeed is a workaround:

So, this does NOT work:

```
a=5
def f
  puts a; # WRONG. a is not known here
end
```

and this works different than you seem to expect:

```
a=5
def f
  a=6
end

puts a # prints 5
f
puts a # prints 5 again
```

But if you define your method like this, it works:

```
a=5
define_method(:f) do
  puts a;  # OK, refers to outer variable a
end
```

By using a block, you create a closure with this, so if you do now a

```
f;
a=6;
f
```

5 and 6 is printed, in this order.

Answer (score 0):

> I have verified that the `index` in the method is not `nil` by printing it. I have also done `index == nil` to double check.
>
> What am I missing here?

Not `index` is `nil`, but `new_array`. The error message says:

```
undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

and refers to the line `new_array << index`. Here, `<<` is the method and `new_array` is the receiver. And for some reason, `new_array` is `nil`.

You probably expected `new_array` to be `[]` because you explicitly said `new_array = []`. But methods have their own local variable scope. If you define a local variable outside of a method, it won't be available inside, or vice-versa.

Typically when referring to an undefined variable you'd get:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_array'
```

but here, the 2nd assignment conceals the actual problem:

```
  new_array = array.each do |index| 
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When Ruby encounters this line, it immediately creates a local variable `new_array` with an initial value of `nil`. (local variables are created when the line is parsed, not when the assignment occurs)

---

To get the expected result, you have to move `new_array = []` *into* the method, get rid of the `new_array = array.each { ...}` assignment and return `new_array` at the end:

```
def substrings(word, array)
  new_array = []

  array.each do |index|
    if index.include?(word)
      new_array << index
    end
  end

  new_array
end
```

The variable names are a bit arbitrary, maybe even misleading. Having `index.include?(word)` looks like you're comparing a numerical index to a string. I'd use something like this:

```
def substrings(substring, words)
  result = []

  words.each do |word|
    if word.include?(substring)
      result << word
    end
  end

  result
end
```

Code-wise, you can incorporate the array into the loop via [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) which will also return the array:

```
def substrings(substring, words)
  words.each_with_object([]) do |word, result|
    if word.include?(substring)
      result << word
    end
  end
end
```

However, selecting elements based on a condition is such a common task that Ruby provides a dedicated method [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-select) – you merely have to return `true` or `false` from the block to indicate whether the element should be selected:

```
def substrings(substring, words)
  words.select do |word|
    word.include?(substring)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! `new_array` being the `nil` value makes a lot of sense. I appreciate the explanation and clarification of the scope.